# Das versus Es as a direct object

Tags: pronoun

How to choose between *es* and *das*? Are they interchangeable?

> - Ich gebe ihm das
>
> versus
>
> - Ich gebe es ihm

Another example:

> - Ich weiss es
>
> versus
>
> - Ich weiss das

Comment: The examples are a bit short on context. As the first example shows, they are not interchangeable, since they require different word order. The concept *direct object* is not really helpful in German. Note, that things also may have non-neutral gender in German, so *ihn* and *sie* might also be involved.

Comment: Have you thought about their similarity to it and that in English?

Answer (score 1):

Note that *das* is a demonstrative pronoun that needs to point to something from (maybe even a visual) *context*. *das* also takes its job as a pro**noun** pretty seriously - It will in most cases refer to a noun.

*Es* is much less restrictive: It does not necessarily need to refer to a noun, but can rather only refer to some general subject matter or some general, even maybe nebulous matter:

> Dem werd' ich'(e)s zeigen

Only tells you he will show him something (very probably some violent action) without much further context.

> Dem werd' ich das zeigen

does, however, need some more context to refer to. ("Das Auto und nicht das andere").

*Es* can also be completely impersonal ("es regnet") and not relate to anything - "das regnet" is only possible in some dialects. "Es ist Nacht" works perfectly, "Das ist Nacht" doesn't, not even in dialects.